# DocuSign composite template signer unique id

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am creating an envelope with composite templates from server templates. I am able to create the envelope successfully with a couple signer recipients.  However, I would like to store a unique id with each signer that I can use later to tie a signer to a person entity from a database.

I thought I could use the signer recipientId field for this unique id value, but when I query the envelope recipients I can see that the recipientId has changed to a single digit number. The value I initially set is a multiple digit number.

Is it possible to send a unique id with a signer that can be retrieved when I query for the envelope's recipients later?

Edit:

There's nothing particularly difficult here but for completeness here's the json for the signer with a custom field.

```
"signers": [  
    {  
        "email":"email@email.com",
        "name":"Name",
        "recipientId":"275",
        "roleName":"RoleOne",
        "tabs":{ ... },
        "status":0,
        "customFields": [  
            "CustId:123"
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set one or more Recipient Custom Fields for this purpose.  It's just an array of text strings that you can get back later.  You'd likely want to format your value as something like "dbid: 19230428".  You can also set custom fields at the document and envelope level if that helps.  Envelope Custom Fields and Document Fields are key/value pairs, however.